# Search String only prints out searches without characters attached

Tags: java, string, search, text

I’m new to java and I am working on a project. I am trying to search a text file for a few 4 character acronyms. It will only show or output when it’s just the 4 characters and nothing else. If there is a space or another character attached to it won’t display it… I have tried to make it show the whole line, but have yet to be successful.

**The contents of text file:**

```
APLM
APLM12345
ABC0
ABC0123456
CSQV
CSQVABCDE
ZIAU
ZIAUABCDE
```

**The output in console:**

```
APLM
ABC0
CSQV
ZIAU
```

**My Code:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class searchPdfText
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    int tokencount;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("TextSearchTest.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    String s = "";
    int linecount = 0;
    ArrayList<String> keywordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("APLM",  "ABC0", "CSQV",  "ZIAU" ));

    String line;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] lineWordList = s.split(" ");
        for (String word : lineWordList)
        {
            if (keywordList.contains(word))
            {
                System.out.println(s);

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What would be your desired output?

Comment: Confuse question, try a better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for [`ArrayList.contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) you will see that it only returns true if your keyword **contains** the provided string from your file. As such, your code is correct when it only outputs the exact matches found for those provided strings in `keywordList`.

Instead, if you want to get matches when a part of the provided string contains a keyword, consider iterating through the input and matching it the other way around:

```
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] lineWordList = s.split(" ");
    for (String word : lineWordList) {
        // JAVA 8
        keywordList.stream().filter(e -> word.contains(e)).findFirst()
                .ifPresent(e -> System.out.println(word));

        // JAVA <8
        for (String keyword : keywordList) {
            if (word.contains(keyword)) {
                System.out.println(s);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, you may consider following [Oracle's Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) with regards to your class name. Each word in your class name should be capitalized. For example, you class might be better named `SearchPdfText`.

Comment: These are all great solutions! Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your `while` code for the output you want:

```
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (s.length() == 4){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

If you want only that 4 specific values just create a method to check it like:

```
public static boolean hasIt(String text){
    String [] list = { "APLM",  "ABC0", "CSQV",  "ZIAU" };
    for ( String s : list ){
        if (s.equals(text)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And your `while` to:

```
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (hasIt(s)){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```